# Informix errors using command oninit

Tags: informix

I am new to Informix. I have an Informix server and I used `oninit -ivy`. Now all my databases or gone. How can I get them back? I don't have any backup.

Answer (score 2):

## Top priority

- ***Don't touch a thing!***
- Contact IBM/Informix Technical Support.
- Ask for down-system assistance.

They may or may not be able to help you — but if they can't help, there's probably no-one who can. (There might be money issues to resolve, of course, in getting Technical Support involved.)

With no backup and after a reinitialization of the system (`-ivy` means "initialize, verbose, and don't ask me silly questions — I know what I'm doing"), there isn't much left to work on.

#### Mitigating circumstances

If your system has multiple dbspaces, or any blob spaces, then those will not have been damaged and the data will be safe.  If you have a default system with a single dbspace, then there is more danger that the information is gone.

How big was the system?  How many databases were affected, and how big was each database?  How crucial is the data in those databases?  There may be ways to get at the data, especially if you know the database schemas, if the worst comes to the worst.  But it won't be easy.  The crucial thing is to do no more damage.  You could make a copy of the primary chunk of the root dbspace and stash that copy safely, but do not try modifying anything.

Just to check, I took a backup copy of a single-chunk server (to a file `copy.0.rootdbs`), then ran `oninit -ivy` on the system to reinitialize it, checked that 'my' databases were not present, then ran `onmode -ky` to take it back down, and then made another copy of the chunk (`copy.1.rootdbs`), and copied `copy.0.rootdbs` back over the chunk and brought the system up in the normal way (`oninit -v`).

There are several bits of good news from this exercise:

1. My original system continued to work with no data loss.
2. The `copy.1.rootdbs` file contained information from the databases in the working database, albeit not in a form that could be found when the reinitialized server was running.

That means that as long as you've got a copy of the minimally modified primary chunk of the root dbspace copied somewhere safely, most of the information for the deleted databases will still be 'there', but it will require some non-negligible efforts to extract that information.  That data will need to be rather valuable to warrant the effort required.  Exactly how much work is involved depends on a variety of factors, such as the size and types of the data in the tables in the various user-defined databases. The more you know about that, the easier the recovery will be — but 'easier' does *not* mean 'easy'.

#### For the future

- Please devise a backup strategy so that you don't run this risk again.
- Do not run `oninit -ivy` again unless you are initializing a new instance of an Informix database server.

#### Alternatives

You could also look for assistance on the IIUG ([International Informix User Group](http://www.iiug.org/)) web site too — or in the mailing lists (`ids` at `iiug.org` would be the one to join).  Membership is free and the emails are not onerous.  However, the standard advice for this circumstance is what I said at the start — hands off and contact Tech Support.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder what version of the Informix product you are using. In the newer versions, Informix 11.70 and 12.10, there is a safety config parameter (FULL_DISK_INIT) that will prevent such accidental disk initialization.
Your best bet is to call IBM Technical Support as suggested by Jonathan above.